# CSS: how to layout 3 columns, 2 are optional

Tags: css

Say I have something like this:

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="main_content"></div>
   <div id="profile_sidebar"></div>
   <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

I want the content to appear in the follow order (left to right): profile_sidebar, main_content, sidebar. I'm trying to float:left profile_sidebar and float:right sidebar -- but it's not showing up as I hope.

Also, profile_sidebar and sidebar are both optional. They may not appear on the page.

**UPDATE 1:** I've updated the content to be like this:

```
<div id="content">
   <div id="profile_sidebar"></div>
   <div id="main_content"></div>
   <div id="sidebar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you know your main content will always be longer than your profile_sidebar, you can position:absolute #profile_sidebar with there being a padding to the left for spacing.  However, if you don't have your sidebars, would you still have the column space or would #main_content stretch to fill the space?

Comment: No, I don't know if main_content will always be longer than profile_sidebar.

Comment: In that case, you could always have a JS script to resize the parent container, but that's a bit of a hack unfortunately.  If you're wanting to go with HTML purity where your elements are laid out in order it's the sacrifice you'd have to make.  I recall reading about an advanced layout system years ago that would have made this possible but that never came to pass (yet).

Comment: Don't want JS. I'm switching the order of main_content and profile_sidebar. Looking at best solution for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can achieve this using just floats without changing the structure, but [then it's easy](http://jsfiddle.net/8yqrk/). I imagine that's not an option?

Edit
[This](http://jsfiddle.net/xmBGE/2/) illustrates jmbertucci's `position:absolute` work-around, and the potential problem.

Comment: It's possible, I guess. It's just that it's not the "proper" order of the content, though. What does `div > div` mean?

Comment: Child selector. It matches only the `div`s contained in `#content`. For the purposes of this it should be no different from `div div`, but I figured you don't want it cascading to descendants of `#main_content` etc. W.r.t. proper order, from a structurual PoV I understand, but the browser doesn't give a damn. However, @jmbertucci is right about `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 1):

this jsfiddle does what you request; i did have to add sizes, (negative) margins and padding, so clearly it's not perfect, but it does rearrange the content display. imo position absolute or fixed would be ideal here, @ least for the side columns. check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/jalbertbowdenii/Zc7ds/26/